# How do I go about a React-native error with Metro when connecting to Android Studio Emulator?

Tags: react-native

I am running a react-native app from vscode and connecting it to Android emulator using Expo Go. This is the error message I get when I run   `npx expo start`

```
 ERROR  Invariant Violation: Picker has been removed from React Native. It can now be installed and imported from '@react-native-picker/picker' instead of 'react-native'. See https://github.com/react-native-picker/picker, js engine: hermes

 ERROR  Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:
* Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
* A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called., js engine: hermes
```

I have tried updating the packages , `@react-native-picker/picker` and `npm install deprecated-react-native-prop-types@5.0.0` 
I also tried updating node version but the error is persistent

Comment: Check your import where you are using the picker. According to the error, it seems like you are importing it from 'react-native' rather than '@react-native-picker/picker'.